# Creating a new command for physical versors

Tags: macros, amsmath

I am trying to create a command in order to achieve this:

I would like to write:

`\ver{x}` , `\ver{y}` , `\ver{z}` , `\ver{r}` , etc...

And I would like to get:

`\hat{\mathbf{x}}` , `\hat{\mathbf{y}}` , `\hat{\mathbf{z}}` , `\hat{\mathbf{r}}` ... respectively.

I need a command capable of doing this for every letter I put between {}.

I have tried `\newcommand{\ver}{\hat\mathbf}` but I am getting error: extra or forgotten }.

I have also tried `\newcommand{\ver}{\hat{\mathbf{•}}}` or `\newcommand{\ver{•}{\hat{\mathbf{•}}}` but I get no result.

If anyone knows how can I solve this problem I will appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome! `\newcommand{\ver}[1]{\hat\mathbf{#1}}` works for me.

Comment: Hello! I have tried it but I am still getting the same error, is there any package I need to make it work?
Thanks!

Comment: I did it! I used \newcommand{\ver}[1]{\hat{\mathbf{#1}}}. Thank you LaTeXereXeTaL!

Comment: Glad it's working for you. Going only by what you included in your post, it seems you didn't allow for the macro to take an argument.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL You missed a pair of braces: `\hat\mathbf{x}` is wrong and produces errors. The correct code would be `\newcommand{\ver}[1]{\hat{\mathbf{#1}}}`

Comment: With all due respect, it works perfectly for me with no errors.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL Did you try it with `amsmath`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might do

```
\newcommand{\ver}[1]{\hat{\mathbf{#1}}}
```

but the result of `\ver{i}` would not be nice, because the i should lose the dot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{mathbf}{OT1}{\familydefault}{\bfdefault}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbf}{mathbf}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\boldimath}{\mathord}{mathbf}{"10}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\boldjmath}{\mathord}{mathbf}{"11}

\newcommand{\ver}[1]{% we assume #1 is a single Latin letter
  \if#1i%
    \hat{\boldimath}%
  \else
    \if#1j%
      \hat{\boldjmath}%
    \else
      \hat{\mathbf{#1}}%
    \fi
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

$\ver{a}+\ver{c}+\ver{i}+\ver{j}+\ver{k}+\ver{x}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

A version that also works with Greek letters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

% for the dotless i and j in bold face upright
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathbf}{OT1}{\familydefault}{\bfdefault}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbf}{mathbf}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\boldimath}{\mathord}{mathbf}{"10}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\boldjmath}{\mathord}{mathbf}{"11}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\ver}{m}
 {% Assumption: the argument is
  % either a single Latin letter or
  % or a single command for a Greek letter
  \token_if_cs:NTF #1
   { \hat{\bm{#1}} } % single Greek letter
   {% check for i or j
    \str_case:nnF { #1 }
     {
      {i}{\hat{\boldimath}} 
      {j}{\hat{\boldjmath}}
     }
     { \hat{\mathbf{#1}} } % single Latin letter not i nor j
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\ver{a}+\ver{c}+\ver{i}+\ver{j}+\ver{k}+\ver{x}+\ver{\alpha}+\ver{\Gamma}$

\end{document}
```

Remember to add `\usepackage{xparse}` if this seems not to work (and update your TeX system).

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's perfect.

Comment: @FacuO.Z. I’ll add also a version for Greek letters. Stay tuned.

Comment: You literally saved my life, Thank you!